# how to configure mockoon endpoint with queryParam?

Tags: java, quarkus, mockoon

I have a get in mockoon with the path /search/data (which is the path in RestClient too) and in RestClient it also sends a queryParam (@QueryParam("dataCode") String dataCode);

How do I configure mockoon to work with the application call (it's java with quarkus).

In the route I just put /search/data. The documentation said not to put any queryParam in the route, but I couldn't understand where to configure it and how in mockoon for this to work. Apart from the port and the route, the only config I put in was a response body that I wanted to return.

I would appreciate if anyone has a better example of how to do this, the documentation was not clear to me.

documentation link

https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/templating/mockoon-request-helpers/#queryparam

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters are not part of the endpoint declaration. To use query parameters, just call your endpoint with them, like this:
`/search/data?dataCode=value`

It will be automatically parsed by Mockoon (relevant documentation: https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/api-endpoints/routing/#query-parameters). You can pass strings, arrays and objects.

After, you can use the query parameters in a template using the helpers you linked to:

```
{{queryParam 'dataCode'}}
```

Or you can use them in rules, to return a 400 when the parameter is missing, and a 200 when the parameter is present, for example. You will find a tutorial on rules [here](https://mockoon.com/tutorials/responses-and-rules/) (example is with a header, but it's ot complicated to transpose to a query parameter).

Comment: I believe I didn´t understand the 'After'. How should I create this template? Where? I did everything I understood but something is still wrong...

Comment: I believe I didn´t understand the 'After'. How should I create this template? Where? I did everything I understood but something is still wrong...

I did everything I understood but something is still wrong...

I added in 'Inline' {{queryParam 'dataCode' }} and 

{
  'my json'
}

In my code, I have

BasicDataResponse resp = personRestClient.getBasicData(request.getDataCode()).;

Client
@Get
@Path("/searchData/byDataCode")
@Produces("application/json")
BasicDataResponse getBasicData(@QueryParam("dataCode") String dataCode)

Comment: Your java code has nothing to do with Mockoon, they are independant.
The idea of Mockoon is to receive a request, and serve/build a response, eventually dynamically by reacting to the query parameters or other elements. 
If you want to build dynamically the content of your inline body (the one you used), you can use the `queryParam` or `queryParamRaw` helpers, and they will be added to the content of Mockoon's response.